# Why "Failed to load JVM DLL"?

Tags: android, android-studio, java-home

I updated android studio from Dolphin to Electric Eel and now it won't start, giving the following error message:

```
Failed to load JVM DLL C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr\\bin\server\jvm.dll
If you already have a JDK installed, define a JAVA_HOME variable in Computer > System Properties > System Settings > Environment Variables.
```

I already have `JAVA_HOME` set but tried different paths, different java versions, uninstalling, installing, etc.
Tried deleting all the caches I could find (probably missing something).
Tried uninstalling android studio multiple times, or going back to the older version and updating again.
While on the older version - tried to change the `JDK` that the studio was using and then update.
Nothing of the above works.

Comment: Have a look at know issues here - https://developer.android.com/studio/known-issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:**
There's a workaround mentioned [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/247854802). It worked for me.
It says to install [Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170)
Installing it provides a "missing `vcruntime140_1.dll` file in bundled Java Runtime" to the Android Studio.

**Old answer:**
I "solved" it by deleting the `jvm.dll` file in `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr\bin\server`.
Then it started actually looking up the `JAVA_HOME` variable and the studio launched.

Answer (score 2):

After some Windows updates, I faced the same problem. Download a fresh copy of [JetBrainsRuntime](https://github.com/JetBrains/JetBrainsRuntime/releases/tag/jbr11_0_16b2043.64) and replace the `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr` folder with this new one.